# cpoptions and parenthesis text objects

Tags: cursor-motions, options

Haskell has a literal syntax for anonymous functions of

```
\pattern0 pattern1 [...] patternN -> expression
```

which interacts oddly with vim's parenthesis text objects when `pattern0` starts with a `(`.

For example in the line

```
foldr (\(a,b) c -> a + b * c) 0 [ (0,1), (2,3) ]
          ^
```

If my cursor is on the `,` in `(a,b)`, I'd like the normal mode command `di(` to delete the `a,b` and leave the cursor on the `)`, like so:

```
foldr (\() c -> a + b * c) 0 [ (0,1), (2,3) ]
         ^
```

However, with `cpoptions=aABceFs`, the `\` prevents the `(` from matching the `)` in `\(a,b)`, so the entire start of the lambda expression is deleted:

```
foldr () c -> a + b * c) 0 [ (0,1), (2,3) ]
       ^
```

With `cpoptions=aABceFsM`, it's a little better as `%` works properly, but the entire lambda expression is deleted:

```
foldr () 0 [ (0,1), (2,3) ]
       ^
```

How can I get `di(` to just delete `a,b`?

Comment: That's really strange. It seems like a bug to me. This isn't the ideal solution, but you could do `:nnoremap di( vT(Ot)d` The only downside is that this doesn't work with `ci(`, `yi(`, `vi(`, `da(` and the endless variations.

Comment: DJ McMayhem: I think you're right. I had this bug using an old version of 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, unpatched). `di(` works as desired in newer versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in vim that was [patched in version 7.4.662](http://ftp.vim.org/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.662), update and `di(` will work as desired.